# innobackupex and creating slave

Tags: mysql, percona-tools

There's master mysql running 5.6.30. Engine InnoDB. `innodb_file_per_table` is used. Slave server is running 5.5.55
Doing next steps:

```
 - (on master) innobackupex --no-timestamp /path/to/backup
 - (on master) innobackupex --apply-log
 - (on slave) /etc/init.d/mysql stop; clearing /var/lib/mysql
 - (on master) rsync -avpP /path/to/backup slave:/var/lib/mysql
 - (on slave) chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
 - (on slave) /etc/init.d/mysql start
 - doing other steps to enable Master-Slave replication...
```

Doing this steps on other servers, where no `innodb_file_per_table` is used, works ok: database successfully copied and replication sets up and works.

But with "multiple .ibd" starting mysql on slave fails with error in corrupted tables. So something I'm doing wrong. But what? Wrong export-import? Slave has to be not older than master? Something else?

error log:

`170430 21:51:05 InnoDB: 5.5.55 started; log sequence number 3110007332942
170430 21:51:05 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
170430 21:51:05 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
170430 21:51:05 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
170430 21:51:05 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist`

Comment: Please provide the error log content or error message from the slave server for better understanding of the question.

Comment: Added error.log to answer. This error says nothing, 'cause 3 times backup was done from running server, every step said everything is OK, transfer was ok too.

Comment: It is advisable to have a _newer_ version in the Slave.  Perhaps an update happened to `master.host`, but perhaps such does not yet exist in 5.5.55.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly safe bet that some of the tables have (including system privilege tables) have structure that MySQL 5.5 can't recognize. MySQL 5.5 and 5.6 is a major version difference (regardless it looks minor) and they are not backwards compatible.

Try adding `skip-grant-tables` to `my.cnf` to see if the problem is only with system tables (when you add `skip-grant-tables`, privilege tables won't be used at all and anyone will be allowed to connect from anywhere with any password). If MySQL would start, that means you have a broken privileges tables and `mysql_install_db` should help you load the blank ones.

If it doesn't help, you may have InnoDB structure changes that MySQL 5.5 can't recognize. In that case, you'll have to use logical backup (mysqldump or mydumper) for such downgrade. BTW, you can use any of the working slaves for it.

BTW, if you're using `innodb_file_per_table` on the master, there's no need NOT to use it on slave. In fact, it doesn't make much sense to.

Comment: Great thanks for so full answer! `skip-grant-tables` allowed to start mysql. I can login to shell, execute SQL statements. So the problem in MySQL versions, not in innobackupex usage by me. Now the answer is: will replication from 5.6 master to 5.5 slave work correctly?

Comment: It's possible to get it to work, but you will need to disable a number of MySQL 5.6 features on the master (these changes require a restart). Here's required my.cnf variables: binlog_checksum=NONE, binlog_row_image=FULL, binlog_rows_query_log_events=OFF, log_bin_use_v1_row_events=1, gtid_mode=OFF. You can find an explanation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-compatibility.html)